# Flutter don't find widget properties : 'child' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart

Because few guys posted some wrong solutions (that wasn't bad ideas), i replied to them then they deleted their posts. I got flag by moderation ... so i post every answer here.

1/ I'm trying to make a simple ElevatedButton using the child and onPressed Properties.

2/ I tried to follow the documentation available here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html

I also used samples but every times i get the same error:
"The named parameter 'child' isn't defined." ('onPressed' also not defined ...')

3/ A picture of the auto-completion properties:
[ElevatedButton Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7WVl.png)

**Flutter version used:**
Flutter 2.0.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b1395592de (10 days ago) • 2021-04-01 14:25:01 -0700
Engine • revision 2dce47073a
Tools • Dart 2.12.2

This is the full code, again i can run&debug but i still have Errors in my
Visual studio compiler as you can see in the screenshot ... and i don't understand why.

I press F5 to run the Emulator then i use "fultter run" to start my app.

[image: Problems]

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    ));

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("HelloWorld"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red[600],
      ),

      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("Hello World"),
            ElevatedButton.icon(
              label: Text("Click"),
              icon: Icon(Icons.airplanemode_active),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.lightBlue,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Text("container"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red[600],
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Container(
          height: 45,
          width: 100,
        ),
       
        color: Colors.pink,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    );
  }
}

class TestFul extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestFulState createState() => _TestFulState();
}

class _TestFulState extends State<TestFul> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Thanks everyone for your fast answer to my post.

surprisingly i can debug and run my code using my emulator.
but i still have the errors as you can see in the image link:
[Problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7WVl.png)

I tried to clean / caches / restart etc... but nothing change.
And of course i'm importing the material.dart
Is it maybe the Flutter 2.0.4 version the cause ?

PS: I'm coding on Visual Studio Code. I don't think that coding without take a look to the errors is a good practice ^^'.

Comment: You shouldn't  be having this error. Make sure that `material.dart` is imported, close your editor and restart fresh, it should work.

Comment: Did you find a proper fix? I am having the same problems. Code runs but only with commands from the terminal, everything is reported as an error. If I run pub get the errors such as 'child isn't defined' go away but then flutter 2.0 widgets are reported as errors (e.g. ElevatedButton) and in this case the app won't even run. I have to run flutter clean again, and I'm back to square one with 'child isn't defined'.

Comment: I didn't fix it, and i don't understand how work stackoverflow for the answers... I get flagged multiple times by answering to people.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I tried your code and it is executing perfectly on my system.
If u still have issues with this Widget(ElevatedButton)then just try to use a simple button and wrap it inside a Card()

```
Card(
      elevation: 5,
      child: //Todo: button
)
```